# Find dates that fall within Monday-Sunday work week

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I currently have a program that finds dates within a table and compares them to a date range and uses them for something else. What I've been using for a week to compare against has been saying `Date + 7`, but I want to just take the dates of the current week from Monday-Sunday and use that as the Date range.

I think the way to go would be to use the current `WeekNum` and find the dates of the Monday and Sunday from there, but I honestly have no idea how to begin to do this from VBA. I would appreciate if anyone had a direction to send me in to accomplish this, or if I'm even thinking about this the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an easy way to get the Monday & following Sunday of the current week:

```
Sub getadate()
    Dim N As Long

    N = Weekday(Date)
    d1 = Date - N + 2
    d2 = d1 + 6
    MsgBox d1 & vbCrLf & d2
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked perfectly. It's a lot simpler than I was thinking it would be, and actually helped me solve some issues I didn't realize I had. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the weekday formula to determine the start and end of the week. The formula would look as such:

`startWeek = Date - (Weekday(Date, vbMonday) - 1)`

and

`endWeek = Date + (7 - Weekday(Date, vbMonday))`

Let me know if this works